# Filter to determain cells to be copied, now copies the last found criteria

Tags: excel, filter, copy, vba

[image: sample solution]

I'm having troubles with the output of my code. Im using a macro to search for some criteria which are labeled:

```
Collection = Trim(Range("lblImportCollection").Value)
        System = Trim(Range("lblImportSystem").Value)
        Tag = Trim(Range("lblImportTag").Value)
```

My filter does search the right cell values where the input values are found, but I want to copy the matched values to a new sheet. Now it just copies the last correct value that is found. Can someone help me with it? What I want:

- If all three criteria match( I want to copy the 3 criteria in a row on the new worksheet)
- If two criteria match( I want to copy the 2 criteria in a row(and not the third one)
- If one criteria match( I want to copy the 1 criteria in a row(so not the second and the third)
- Also: All resulting matches must fill a new row. 
  I hope I gave enough information, it's a bit hard to explain. If you have questions, let me know :)

---

```
Sub FilterButton()
    Dim XUsedRange As Range
    Dim SourceRange As Range, DestRange As Range
    Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet, Lr As Long
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Integer
    Dim zLastRow As Integer
    Dim test As String
    Dim TempRange As Range

    Dim Collection As String
    Dim System As String
    Dim Tag As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With


    Collection = Trim(Range("lblImportCollection").Value)
    System = Trim(Range("lblImportSystem").Value)
    Tag = Trim(Range("lblImportTag").Value)

    'fill in the Source Sheet and range
    Set XUsedRange = Sheets("Imported Data").UsedRange
    Set ZUsedRange = Sheets("Test").Range("A:C")

    'Fill in the destination sheet and find the last known cell
    Set DestSheet = Sheets("Test")

    Set SrcSheet = Sheets("Imported Data")

    'With the information on the new sheet


    iLastRow = XUsedRange.End(xlDown).Row
    zLastRow = ZUsedRange.End(xlUp).Row
    Set SourceRange = SrcSheet.Range("A2:A" & CStr(iLastRow))
    Set DestRange = DestSheet.Range("A2:C" & CStr(zLastRow))

    With SourceRange
        Set c = SourceRange.Find(What:=Collection, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
            MsgBox ("Found " & Collection & " on address:" & c.Address)
            c.Copy
            DestRange.PasteSpecial

            If System = SrcSheet.Range("B" & CStr(c.Row) & ":B" & CStr(c.Row)) Then

            MsgBox ("The system is " & SrcSheet.Range("B" & CStr(c.Row) & ":B" & CStr(c.Row)))
            'DestSheet.Range ("B" & CStr(c.Row) & ":B" & CStr(c.Row))

            SrcSheet.Range("B" & CStr(c.Row) & ":B" & CStr(c.Row)).Copy
            DestRange.PasteSpecial

            If Tag = SrcSheet.Range("C" & CStr(c.Row) & ":C" & CStr(c.Row)) Then

            MsgBox ("The tag is" & SrcSheet.Range("C" & CStr(c.Row) & ":C" & CStr(c.Row)))
            'DestSheet.Range ("C" & CStr(c.Row) & ":C" & CStr(c.Row))

            SrcSheet.Range("C" & CStr(c.Row) & ":C" & CStr(c.Row)).Copy
            DestRange.PasteSpecial

            End If
            End If
            Set c = SourceRange.FindNext(c)
            Loop While (Not c Is Nothing) And (c.Address <> firstAddress)
        Else
            MsgBox (Collection & " is NOT Found ")

        End If
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There are lot of problems with the code that I can see... So I will start with few questions first and as you answer them I will be updating my answer below. First Question Are `lblImportCollection`, `lblImportSystem`, `lblImportTag` Single cells?

Comment: Yes they are single cells :)!

Comment: `Collection (A1)                  System (B1)           Tag(C1)`
`"lblImportCollection"(A2)    lblImportSystem(B2)    lblImportTag(C2)`

Like this :) , the user only changes the lables. The A1,B1,C1 cells 
are to notify the user that they must fill in a collection, system or tag. Also the `lblImportCollection` is a MUST to fill in, thats why the code starts with: `Set c = SourceRange.Find(What:=Collection, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns` . After a collection is noticed than it will search for the other labels.

Comment: Refresh the page ;) Posted an answwer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned there are couple of problems with the code

1. Please use `Option Explicit`. That will ensure that you define your variables
2. When you define a variable which is meant to store Excel Row number then instead of `Integer`, use `Long`
3. Avoid the use of `UsedRange`. Get the Actual range which has "Data". Since you are only concerned with Col A, use that to find the last row. We can always use `.Offset()` to check for `Criteria2` and `Criteria3`
4. Comment your code with appropriate "comments". I had a tough time understanding it.

Is this what you are trying?

**Code: (UNTESTED)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterButton()
    Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet, DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, zLastRow As Long
    Dim Collection As String, System As String, Tag As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    '~~> Set your sheet
    Set DestSheet = Sheets("Test")
    Set SrcSheet = Sheets("Imported Data")

    '~~> Find Last Row in Col A in the source sheet
    With SrcSheet
        iLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    '~~> Find Last "Available Row for Output" in Col A in the destination sheet
    With DestSheet
        zLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    '~~> Set your ranges
    Set SourceRange = SrcSheet.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow)

    '~~> Search values
    Collection = Trim(Range("lblImportCollection").Value)
    System = Trim(Range("lblImportSystem").Value)
    Tag = Trim(Range("lblImportTag").Value)

    With SourceRange
        '~~> Match 1st Criteria
        Set aCell = .Find(What:=Collection, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            '~~> Copy A:C. Then match for Crit B and Crit C and remove what is not required
            DestSheet.Range("A" & zLastRow & ":" & "C" & zLastRow).Value = _
            SrcSheet.Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":" & "C" & aCell.Row).Value

            '~~> Match 2nd Criteria
            If aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = System Then
                '~~> Match 3rd Criteria
                If aCell.Offset(, 2).Value <> Tag Then _
                DestSheet.Range("C" & zLastRow).ClearContents
            Else
                DestSheet.Range("B" & zLastRow).ClearContents
            End If

            '~~> Increase last row by 1 for output
            zLastRow = zLastRow + 1

            Do
                Set aCell = .FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                    '~~> Copy A:C. Then match for Crit B and Crit C
                    DestSheet.Range("A" & zLastRow & ":" & "C" & zLastRow).Value = _
                    SrcSheet.Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":" & "C" & aCell.Row).Value

                    '~~> Match 2nd Criteria
                    If aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = System Then
                        '~~> Match 3rd Criteria
                        If aCell.Offset(, 2).Value <> Tag Then _
                        DestSheet.Range("C" & zLastRow).ClearContents
                    Else
                        DestSheet.Range("B" & zLastRow).ClearContents
                    End If

                    '~~> Increase last row by 1 for output
                    zLastRow = zLastRow + 1
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox Collection & " not Found"
        End If
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterButton()
    Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet, DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, zLastRow As Long
    Dim Collection As String, System As String, Tag As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    '~~> Set your sheet
    Set DestSheet = Sheets("Test")
    Set SrcSheet = Sheets("Imported Data")

    '~~> Find Last Row in Col A in the source sheet
    With SrcSheet
        iLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    '~~> Find Last "Available Row for Output" in Col A in the destination sheet
    With DestSheet
        zLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    '~~> Set your ranges
    Set SourceRange = SrcSheet.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow)

    '~~> Search values
    Collection = Trim(Range("lblImportCollection").Value)
    System = Trim(Range("lblImportSystem").Value)
    Tag = Trim(Range("lblImportTag").Value)

    With SourceRange
        '~~> Match 1st Criteria
        Set aCell = .Find(What:=Collection, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            '~~> Copy A:C. Then match for Crit B and Crit C and remove what is not required
            DestSheet.Range("A" & zLastRow & ":" & "C" & zLastRow).Value = _
            SrcSheet.Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":" & "C" & aCell.Row).Value

            '~~> Match 2nd Criteria
            If Len(Trim(System)) = 0 Or _
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Value <> System Then _
            DestSheet.Range("B" & zLastRow).ClearContents

            '~~> Match 3rd Criteria
            If Len(Trim(Tag)) = 0 Or _
            aCell.Offset(, 2).Value <> Tag Then _
            DestSheet.Range("C" & zLastRow).ClearContents

            '~~> Increase last row by 1 for output
            zLastRow = zLastRow + 1

            Do
                Set aCell = .FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                    '~~> Match 2nd Criteria
                    If Len(Trim(System)) = 0 Or _
                    aCell.Offset(, 1).Value <> System Then _
                    DestSheet.Range("B" & zLastRow).ClearContents

                    '~~> Match 3rd Criteria
                    If Len(Trim(Tag)) = 0 Or _
                    aCell.Offset(, 2).Value <> Tag Then _
                    DestSheet.Range("C" & zLastRow).ClearContents

                    '~~> Increase last row by 1 for output
                    zLastRow = zLastRow + 1
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox Collection & " not Found"
        End If
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks :)! That's almost what I want. 
- You know a way to make it so that if filter the 2nd criteria doesn't match, it won't copy and paste in the other sheet? So that it only copy's when all criteria are exactly true?
- And if criteria 2 is empty(but 3 is filled) it will only display the ones that match to criteria 1 and 3?
- Also for criteria 3 is empty(but 2 is filled) that it will only display the ones that match criteria 1 and 2?

Comment: I see you h ave edited the comment.. one moment. let me read  it again.

Comment: I am confused now. `So that it only copy's when all criteria are exactly true` so how come you have now further conditions?

Comment: Hmmmmm, well that part I am trying to figure out myself.. I can tell you the solution I want in total.
`The user must fill in the 1st criteria, it can either choose to fill in the 2nd or 3rd criteria(or fill them in both). `
Then it goes through the data to match... the matching results are displayed on sheet `"Test"`. What I've not told is that I want the matched results from sheet `"Imported Data"` to also copy their value of cell E. `So it copies (A,B,C) like it does now but also E`(this doesnt have to match or anything, and must be placed next to the resulting`(pasted)` values).

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of an example output?

Comment: I attached an image file from my computer, can't see it though.. I hope u can see it :)

Comment: Can u open the image, in the link below? Regards

Comment: So you want to copy only if all the 3 criteria is met? Also please delete the answer that you posted. Since the image is already uploaded in the question.

Comment: Yes :), but if criteria 2 or 3 is left blank it shouldn't met all criteria. as example: if the second criteria isn't filled in by the user it should only copy those who match criteria 1 and 3.

Comment: Ah so there is a possibility that one of the values Crit1,2 or 3 will not be there?

Comment: Yes :)! But Crit 1 is an exception to that. Crit 1 is always there :)

Comment: Check the followup code in the post above. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for all the help again! Almost what I want, I want all possible matches to be displayed. And if they match all criteria, also copy column E from the sheet "Imported Data"

Comment: I think I have given you enough code for you to understand and tweak it as per your requirements ;)

Comment: I've found the issue :)! Thanks for all the help!